# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,128,3) into shape (128,128,3,3)

Tags: model, callback, broadcast, valueerror, efficientnet

[ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,128,3) into shape (128,128,3,3) net_final.fit problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cznFe.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: weights_file = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Sound-based-bird-species-detection-master/app/model/model.h5'
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=5, mode='auto', verbose=2)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(weights_file, monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, verbose=2)
callbacks = [early_stopping, model_checkpoint]

model_fit = net_final.fit(
    train_batches,validation_data = valid_batches,
    steps_per_epoch=1000,
    epochs=5,
    callbacks=callbacks)

Comment: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,128,3) into shape (128,128,3,3)